# Date axis labels in ggplot2 is one day behind

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot with dates on the x-axis in R using `ggplot2` and the `scales` library. The problem is, when I am using the command `scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks(width = "1 day"), labels=date_format("%e. %b"))`, the breaks seems to be OK, but the labels are one day behind. So, for the data point for 1st of May, the label is the 30th of April.

I guess it is because I use the scale for discrete value, and it is intended for continuous data. Anyway, how can I make sure that the label for the 1st of May says 1st of May?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

start <- "2015-05-01 00:00:00"
end <- "2015-05-10 00:00:00"

df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(as.POSIXct(start), as.POSIXct(end), by = "1 day"),
  y = runif(10, 0, 20)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks(width = "1 day"), labels=date_format("%e. %b"))
```

### Solution with help from @Deena

```
breaks.index <- match(unique(format(df$x, "%d. %b")), format(df$x, "%d. %b"))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = df$x[breaks.index],
  labels = format(df$x[breaks.index], "%e. %b"))
```

Comment: The example you posted looks fine to me. Dates and values are aligned.

Comment: The dates in the data frame is May 1, May 2, and up to May 10, and the labels goes from April 30 to May 9.

Comment: When I ran your code, the graph I received does not include the 30th of April at all. You should probably start a new R session and try again.

Comment: Strange. I have tried to restart R and RStudio--nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't know why we are getting 30April on the axis. But following is a work around:

```
#works 
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks(width = "day")) 

#doesn't work
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks(width = "day") , labels = date_format("%d. %b")) 

#Work around
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks =df$x , labels = format(df$x, "%d. %b"))
```

Comment: The problem is when my data changes to hourly values for instance. Then I will have a huge amount of labels.

Comment: @Christoffer You can always index df$x and format(df$x, "%d. %b"). If you get hourly data and need daily labels, try to go for something like :  `myBreak.index = which(unique( format (df$x, "%d. %b")) `  , then use `df$x[myBreak.index]` and `format(df$x, "%d. %b") [myBreak.index]`

Comment: Great @Deena. I had to use `match()` instead of `which()`. See the edit in the original question.

Comment: Great that it works nor @Christoffer ! Another thing that I've just noticed, if your data time series has more than a year value, include the year value in the indexing also. ie: `breaks.index <- match(unique(format(df$x, "%d. %b %Y")), format(df$x, "%d. %b %Y"))
`